# Relatório mostrando o indice da Coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, procedure

Estou com uma dúvida para gerar um relatório, preciso que ele pegue os dados de uma tabela SQL e no lugar no nome da tabela preciso do ID dela, abaixo os dados que a consulta gera

```
     COD_CLIENTE NOME        ENDERECO             CPF                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

      2 Fulano               Av. Rio Branco       2837462890           
      3 Ciclano              Rua Zero             4625427282           
      4 Beltrano             Rua Doze             2634623637
```

> Criei essa procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COLUNAS_TESTE AS 
Cursor linha is
Select cod_cliente, nome, endereco, cpf from clientes where rownum < 4;

rLin linha%rowtype;

BEGIN
Open linha;
Loop

Fetch linha into rLin;

Exit when linha%notFound;

        dbms_output.put_line('Linha: '||rLin.cod_cliente||' Coluna: 2'||' Valor: '||rLin.Nome);
        dbms_output.put_line('Linha: '||rLin.cod_cliente||' Coluna: 3'||' Valor: '||rLin.Endereco);
        dbms_output.put_line('Linha: '||rLin.cod_cliente||' Coluna: 4'||' Valor: '||rLin.CPF);
End loop;
Close linha;
END;
```

> Que gera esse resultado

```
Linha: 2 Coluna: 2 Valor: Fulano
Linha: 2 Coluna: 3 Valor: Av. Rio Branco
Linha: 2 Coluna: 4 Valor: 2837462890
Linha: 3 Coluna: 2 Valor: Ciclano
Linha: 3 Coluna: 3 Valor: Rua Zero
Linha: 3 Coluna: 4 Valor: 4625427282
Linha: 4 Coluna: 2 Valor: Beltrano
Linha: 4 Coluna: 3 Valor: Rua Doze
Linha: 4 Coluna: 4 Valor: 2634623637
```

Linha e valor OK, ele pega do codigo, mas preciso de 2 relatorios, um que no lugar da coluna ele coloque o nome do campo, e outro que coloque o indice da coluna, ali fiz a gambiarra de colocar o "fixo", mas preciso dele dinamicamente, espero que tenha conseguido explicar.

Até consegui fazer um um select que busca esse dados, mas não soube relacionar ele com a minha coluna, se alguem puder ajudar e eu tenha conseguido explicar o problema.

```
select COLUNAS.COLUMN_ID AS COLUNAS_ID ,COLUNAS.COLUMN_NAME AS COLUNAS_NOME
   from USER_TAB_COLUMNS COLUNAS
   where COLUNAS.TABLE_NAME = 'CLIENTES';
```

Comment: uma procedure retornando um select já não era o suficiente? precisa realmente fazer tudo isso que você fez na procedure? um relatório é diferente do outro, então é natural que exista uma procedure para cada relatório. Só criar outras procedures com o mesmo formato e modificar o dado que tu quer diferente.

Comment: sim, sera feito 2 procedure, 1 para cada relatorio, só quero saber, como faço para aqueles valores que estão na coluna sejam preenchidos dinamicamente, hoje eles estão fixos, e para a outra proc, como fazer para preencher o campo coluna com o nome da coluna, não com seu valor, espero que tenha conseguido explicar corretamente. Quanto ao resultado final, o cliente quer que seja apresentado desse jeito que esta na tela, como gera resultado. Obrigado

Comment: Veja se o AskTom ajuda   https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2170326695312     https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:470474702614

Comment: Não tenho um ambiente para testar, mas me parece que o que você precisa é uma consulta usando o comando UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 1):

Deu trabalho, mas foi divertido :-)

```
WITH 
raw_xml AS (
  -- Obtem um flaten XML da tabela departments
  SELECT TRIM(COLUMN_VALUE) AS vals
  FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(CURSOR(SELECT * FROM departments)))
),  
extract_row_tag AS (
  -- Substitui a tag <ROW> por vazio
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(vals, '<ROW>', '') AS vals
  FROM raw_xml
),
extract_end_tags AS (
  -- Substitui todas as end tags por vazio
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(vals, '</[[:print:]]+>', '') AS vals
  FROM extract_row_tag
), 
replace_start_sign AS (
  -- Substitui os sinais de maior por vazio
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(vals, '<', '') AS vals
  FROM extract_end_tags
),
replace_end_sign AS (
  -- Substitui os sinais de menor por dois pontos
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(vals, '>', ':') AS vals
  FROM replace_start_sign
)
SELECT * FROM replace_end_sign;
```

Nesse exemplo, estou montando o relatório a partir da tabela **departments**, mas essa *query* funciona com qualquer tabela e qualquer número de campos.

Separei em sucessivas queries apenas para entendimento. Num relatório gigante, acredito que o WITH poderia gerar um certo *overhead* desnecessariamente.

O pulo do gato está na primeira *query*, que transforma as linhas da tabela em linhas *XML like*. As outras *queries* são apenas para limpeza e formatação.

A *function* XMLSEQUENCE está marcada como *deprecated*, mas ainda é suportada.

Comment: Show, vou dar uma analisada nela, para entender bem o funcionamento, mas um belo trabalho :), mas infelizmente não é o que preciso, necessito que no relatorio apareca o ID do indice da coluna, atualmente estou passando ele fixo, mas se adicionar uma coluna, tenho que alterar tb, queria dinamico, como esta abaixo o exemplo, mas obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso você irá precisar de dois cursores, um para as linhas e outro para as colunas.

Segue abaixo a solução:

```
DECLARE
  nome_tabela VARCHAR(32) := 'CLIENTES';
  nome_coluna VARCHAR2(32);
  id_coluna   NUMBER(10);
  query_str   VARCHAR2(100);
  mycount     NUMBER;
  valor       VARCHAR2(4000);

  CURSOR linha
  IS
    SELECT rownum AS num_linha,
      cod_cliente,
      nome,
      endereco,
      cpf
    FROM clientes
    WHERE rownum < 4;

  rLin linha%rowtype;

  CURSOR colunas (tabela VARCHAR2)
  IS
    SELECT column_name,
      column_id
    FROM user_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name = tabela
    ORDER BY column_id;

BEGIN
  OPEN linha;

  LOOP
    FETCH linha INTO rLin;
    EXIT
  WHEN linha%notFound;
    OPEN colunas (nome_tabela);

    LOOP
      FETCH colunas INTO nome_coluna,id_coluna;
      EXIT
    WHEN colunas%NOTFOUND;
      query_str := 'Select CAST('|| nome_coluna ||' AS VARCHAR2(4000)) from clientes where cod_cliente = '||rLin.cod_cliente;
      EXECUTE immediate query_str INTO valor;
      dbms_output.put_line('Linha: '||rLin.num_linha||' Coluna: '||id_coluna||' Valor: '||valor);

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE colunas;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE linha;
END;
```

Código usado para criar a tabela de testes:

```
create table clientes (cod_cliente number, nome varchar2(200), endereco varchar(200), cpf varchar2(11));

insert into clientes values (2,'Fulano','Av. Rio Branco','2837462890');
insert into clientes values  (3,'Ciclano','Rua Zero','4625427282');
insert into clientes values  (4,'Beltrano', 'Rua Doze','2634623637');
```

Essa resposta foi feita com base [nesse tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642079/query-each-column-of-a-table-in-a-loop-oracle-database).